# How to avoid from The process cannot access the file XXX.XXX because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I transfer file from computer  to computer  Through a WebService.

After the file was transfer I need to read its size.

When I try to read the file size I get:

> The process cannot access the file XXX.XXX because it is being used by another process

What can I do to avoid this error?

i read the file like this:

```
 LocalFileSize = File.Open(TermSendName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read).Length.ToString();
```

how to close this ?

Comment: Please post your current code - you are leaving a handle to the file open, and we need to know where it is.

Comment: Did you try to use FileInfo.Length property  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx. I think it should work with open files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are using a `FileStream` to read the file.

Close the stream when the transfer has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(TermSendName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

LocalFileSize = stream.Length.ToString();

stream.Close();
```

If you only want to get length of file you can also do something like

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
string size = fileInfo.Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following Stack Overflow link, I faced the same issue and got fixed here:

[The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687156/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process-c)